# 3Button isn't clicking (need help)

Tags: python, windows, playwright, playwright-python, playwright-test

I've had this issue for a couple of days now and I can't figure out the fix. I am new to Playwright and am trying to make it click a button on janitorai.com. There are two buttons that would both make the code work if clicked, I just need to click one of them. No matter what different combinations of code using the page.click() function I try, it doesn't click it. Here is my code:

```
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright
import time
with sync_playwright() as p:
browser = p.firefox.launch(headless=False)
page = browser.new_page()
page.goto('https://www.janitorai.com/login')
page.fill('input[type="email"]#email', 'Censored for privacy reasons')
page.fill('input[type="password"]#password', 'Censored for privacy reasons')
page.click('button[type="submit"].chakra-button')
page.wait_for_selector('button.chakra-button.css-1nlwyv4').click()
page.click('.chakra-link.css-939ljh')
#on the chat page now
time.sleep(2)
page.click('span.css-h8nn2p') #this is the button that doesn't work
print("Press the Enter key to close the browser...")
input()
The last page.click() doesn't work.
```

In the picture provided, I want to click either one of those two buttons.
Here is the HTML code for both buttons:

Red button:
span class="css-h8nn2p"API not ready! Click to setup./span

Menu button:

```
<button id="menu-button-:r3:" class="chakra-button chakra-menu\_\_menu-button css-48kqv5" type="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="menu" aria-controls="menu-list-:r3:"> x

<span class="chakra-button\_\_icon css-1wh2kri">

<svg stroke="currentColor" fill="currentColor" stroke-width="0" aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" height="1em" width="1em" xmlns="[http://www.w3.org/2000/svg](http://www.w3.org/2000/svg)">

<path d="M16 132h416c8.837 0 16-7.163 16-16V76c0-8.837-7.163-16-16-16H16C7.163 60 0 67.163 0 76v40c0 8.837 7.163 16 16 16zm0 160h416c8.837 0 16-7.163 16-16v-40c0-8.837-7.163-16-16-16H16c-8.837 0-16 7.163-16 16v40c0 8.837 7.163 16 16 16zm0 160h416c8.837 0 16-7.163 16-16v-40c0-8.837-7.163-16-16-16H16c-8.837 0-16 7.163-16 16v40c0 8.837 7.163 16 16 16z"></path>
```

Thank you for any help!

I have tried a every different possible combination of the page.click() command paired with all of the html code that I provided. Nothing changed, the button still wasn't clicked. When the button clicks, a pop up appears.

Comment: It seems like you have to get the locator for this button from its parent before you can perform an action on it. For exemple, it must be something like: div1>div2>span. In addition, try not to use implicit await, you can make it wait until the button is ready to be clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use option `force: true` for you click command:

```
page.click('span.css-h8nn2p', force=True)
```